# PGP decryption in Apache camel route

Tags: apache-camel, pgp

I'm trying to decrypt a pgp encrypted file from an sftp server in apache camel. I've googled around and found a few threads, but have gotten no real leads as how to go pgp decryption in an apache camel route. Has anyone done this and willing to point me in a direction or share code?

Answer (score 1):

I dont recall any PGP component in Camel. You can of course just use Java code from a bean to decrypt the file.

However we love contributions so a new PGP data format may come handy
http://camel.apache.org/data-format